# Tuples and Dictionaries contained within a List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I am trying to a obtain a specific dictionary from within a list that contains both tuples and dictionaries. How would I go about returning the dictionary with key 'k' from the list below?

```
lst = [('apple', 1), ('banana', 2), {'k': [1,2,3]}, {'l': [4,5,6]}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your

```
lst = [('apple', 1), ('banana', 2), {'k': [1,2,3]}, {'l': [4,5,6]}]
```

using

```
next(elem for elem in lst if isinstance(elem, dict) and 'k' in elem)
```

returns

```
{'k': [1, 2, 3]}
```

i.e. the first object of your list which is a dictionary and contains key 'k'.

This raises `StopIteration` if no such object is found. If you want to return something else, e.g. `None`, use this:

```
next((elem for elem in lst if isinstance(elem, dict) and 'k' in elem), None)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def return_dict(lst):
    for item in lst:
       if isinstance(item,dict) and 'k' in item:
          return item
    raise Exception("Item not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind being a bit ugly in your code I would iterate through the list and check each element. Example:

```
def find_dict(lst):
    for element in lst:
        if type(element) == dict:
            if 'k' in element.keys():
                return element
```

There should be a more pythonic way for this probably.

Comment: Took too long typing this .. teamProbable wins!